Is there a way to write the energy functional so that it is parametrized by arc length instead of time?
If I have the energy functional
$g_{ij}\dot{q}^i\dot{q}^j$
Is there a way to write it so the q dots are not the derivatives with respect to time but arch length?

Wouldn't arc length be the $q$ term? So then you'd have $q'=dq/dq$?

so my energy functional would be something like: $g_{ij} q'^i q'^j$ ?

$dq/dq=1$, so that probably wouldn't be right. It might be better to start a bit further back. What system are you considering that you'd want to write your kinetic energy in terms of some parameter's derivative w.r.t. arc length instead of a velocity?

The system is just an agent moving on a manifold, I think It would make it easier to work with
